# Excel : VLOOKUP returns the last value in the column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I've got a problem with the vlookup() function. I search a text in a table (A column) and want to return the E-column value (E10). However, vlookup() returns the last value of the column (E35). I guess I made a mistake but I've really no clue about it. Could you help me ?

[Here is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00U8f.jpg)

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify parameter 4 (can be 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'), so the match be *exact*. Check your search value and the table content for extra blanks before or after the texts (i.e.: -using `_` for a blank - `_Aaron` != `Aaron_` != `Aaron`, etc.)

Comment: If I put the parameter 4, it returns #N/A.  I've double checked the blanks into the value and the table.

Comment: That proves the point - it does not find an exact match. From a screen copy, I can't tell where the texts would be different. Try to put A10 instead C3 in the first param, then there can be no different spelling. Or put `=c3=a10` in a free cell and see if they are equal. that is the root of your issue.

Comment: Yes, you had right. I used the trim() function and it found a blank. Thanks for your support.